# windows power shell equivalent of sort -u

Tags: powershell, findstr

Is there a windows power shell equivalent to `sort -u`*?

```
> findstr /n "component" .\relevant.json | Measure-Object -line # | sort -u ?
```

---

*removing duplicate lines from search results

Comment: `Sort-Object -Unique` or if sorting is unwanted `Select-Object -Unique`

Comment: `sort -u` even works in PowerShell, due to `sort` being an alias for `Sort-Object` and PowerShell being able to bind arguments even with abbreviated names, as long as there is no ambiguation.

Comment: Thanks ! both `Sort-Object -Unique` and `sort -u` work. Interestingly enough, `Select-Object -Unique` is *considerably slower*, and returns a *different answer* than sorting

Comment: `Select-Object -Unique` is case sensitive whereas `Sort-Object -Unique` is not: `'A', 'a' | Select-Object -Unique` // `'A', 'a' | Sort-Object -Unique` aside from that you may want to clarify what you mean than "different answer". And yes, `Select-Object` is very slow

Comment: why on earth do you use `findstr` with powershell? It's even more terrible when using that for json when there are already `Select-String` and `Convert*-Json` in PowerShell. What if the json string isn't formatting in multiple lines? Your code will fail miserably

Comment: `Select-Object -Unique` is obviously slower, because it has to store results in a Set and lookup if the object already existed in that set, unlike `Sort-Object` where duplicate detection is trivial

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I meant the result of counting matches with `Measure-Object -line`. Your answer about case-ignoring was indeed the reason for the difference, thanks !

Comment: @phuclv I am completely clueless about powershell (as it probably shows) I basically look for the equivalents of the tools I use on linux - thanks for the tip !